# Filter out terms aggregation buckets in elasticsearch after applying aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Below is snapshot of the dataset:

```
recordNo    employeeId      employeeStatus   employeeAddr
1           employeeA       Permanent   
2           employeeA                         ABC
3           employeeB       Contract    
4           employeeB                         CDE
```

I want to get the list of employees along with employeeStatus and employeeAddr.

So I am using terms aggregation on employeeId and then using sub-aggregations of employeeStatus and employeeAddr to get these details.
Below query returns the results correctly.

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "Employee": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "employeeID"
            
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "employeeStatus": {
                    "terms": {"field": "employeeStatus"}
                },
                "employeeAddr": {
                    "terms": {"field": "employeeAddr"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want only the employees which are in Permanent status. So I am applying filter aggregation.

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "filter_Employee_employeeID": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "employeeStatus": {"query": "Permanent"}
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "Employee": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "employeeID"
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "employeeStatus": {
                            "terms": {"field": "employeeStatus"}
                        },
                        "employeeAddr": {
                            "terms": {"field": "employeeAddr"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    

}
```

Now the problem is that the employeeAddr aggregation returns no buckets for employeeA because record 2 gets filtered out before the aggregation is done.

Assuming that I cannot modify the data set and I want to achieve the result with a single elastic query, how can I do it?

I checked the Bucket Selector pipeline aggregation but it only works for metric aggregations.
Is there a way to filter out term buckets after the aggregation is applied?

Comment: what is your expected search result ?

Comment: I need all the details of Permanent employees. So for this eg, the expected output is that employeeA bucket should be returned and in sub aggregations, the buckets "Permanent" for employeeStatus and "ABC" for employeeAddr should be returned. Currently in the result, "ABC" bucket is not retuned under employeeAddr because the query in the filter agg removes the record 2 of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to preserve the aggregations even if you use some kind of filter. To achieve that, try using the **post_filter** clause.

You can check the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html#post-filter)

The clause is applied "outside" the aggregation. Using your example, it should look like this:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "filter_Employee_employeeID": {
      "aggregations": {
        "Employee": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "employeeID"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "employeeStatus": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "employeeStatus"
              }
            },
            "employeeAddr": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "employeeAddr"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "employeeStatus": {
              "query": "Permanent"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vitor, thanks for the input. If I understood the documentation correctly, the post_filter will filter out the results in the "hits" section of the response. I need to apply the filter on the aggregation result because the aggregation result is processed to show on the client side. Above I have pasted just a snippet of the query but there are also sub-aggregations for sub-entities under Employee and pagination support for the aggregation buckets, so I need the filtered data in the hierarchy format.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a combination of the `include` field for the `terms` aggregation, plus using a `bucket_selector` with document count would give you the desired result.

Filtering term values is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/filter-search-results.html).

Bucket selector using document count is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#_special_paths)

- the subtlety here is that, yes you need numeric values, but you can also reference meta/custom fields that elasticsearch has

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "Employee": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "employeeId.keyword"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "employeeStatus": {
                    "terms": {"field": "employeeStatus", "include": "Permanent"}
                },
                "employeeAddr": {
                    "terms": {"field": "employeeAddr"}
                },
                "min_bucket_selector": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "count": "employeeStatus._bucket_count" 
                    },
                    "script": {
                      "source": "params.count != 0"
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this on 7.10 and it worked, returning only employeeA, with the address included.